# How to completion Typescript in html using vscode API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

To achieve ts or js completion in html.
eg:
 ng-if="expression"
 {{expression}}

when input those expression,I want to achieve completion ts or js expression.
Which vscode api can i use?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API, from what I know. If you want to write a code completion provider you are also responsible for creating the code completion candidates list in your extension by parsing the document etc.